# Can I replace my bathroom's floor tile before replacing the tub?

Tags: bathroom, floor, bathtub

I am doing a complete upgrade in a bathroom. Money is a huge factor. But, I'd rather hire a contractor to rr the tub surround (currently one piece). I'll do everything else myself.
Can I put a tile floor BEFORE the old tub/shower is taken out and replaced? Then do the tub surround months later?
Or should I have the shower/tub (4 pc) installed before I do the floor?

Comment: I like @isherwood answer I would add that you can possibly tile everything except the last row  at the tub. After the rr finish that run.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, but the problem is that you don't know that the new tub will be exactly the same width. Usually flooring is one of the last things completed in a bathroom remodel.

If your current tub is fiberglass (and not cast-iron) you may be able to cut out the lower portion of the face to allow you to run tile underneath for a short distance. You'd then install your new tub above tile level, using filler plywood or whatever.

Comment: that's my concern... but couldn't I also assume that a 30" tub is a 30" tub? If I had to replace the tub because someone dropped a typewriter inside it, I should be able to do that without redoing the floor. No?